# Not getting the last item in the list model in xamarin

Tags: arrays, json, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am using this method with the list as below to retrieve the Jason list of items in the model

```
   private List<ResturentPair> GetDishItems(List<Resturent> list)
        {
            var res = new List<ResturentPair>();           
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count ; i++)
            {
                res.Add(new ResturentPair {Item1 = (i < list.Count - 1 ? list[i] : null) , Item2 = ((i < list.Count - 1 && i + 1 < list.Count - 1 )? list[i+1] : null) , Item3 = ((i < list.Count - 1 && i + 2 < list.Count - 1  )? list[i+2] : null)});               

                i = i + 2;              
            }
            return res;          

        }
```

the `List<ResturentPair>` is collection of food items where the method returns from item 1 to the end but always the method returns with 1 item less than the number of items in the collection , for example say `List<ResturentPair>` contains items of 10 , it returns only 9 , is that the issue with the `for` loop or the variable `i`, help will be appreciated, Thank you in advance for the support

Comment: have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?  If each Pair contains 3 items, why are you incrementing by 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key is that:

```
Item1 = (i <= list.Count - 1 ? list[i] : null)
```

instead of

```
Item1 = (i < list.Count - 1 ? list[i] : null)
```

You should do a test for you logic part area, just simply report by using

```
var firstLogic = (i < list.Count - 1 ? list[i] : null) ;
var secondLogic = i < list.Count - 1 && i + 1 < list.Count - 1;
var thirdLogic = i < list.Count - 1 && i + 2 < list.Count - 1;
```

[First loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqyvz.png)
[Second loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj2c3.png)